# Import of large CSV file using Pandas - Avoid truncated output

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to import a large CSV data file into Pycharm using Pandas Import? Because no matter what I do, the output seen in the run terminal is severely truncated which is not good for any selection or cleaning data operations.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The output in the terminal is not what pandas has in memory, it's just a compact representation of your DataFrame. All your data are still there, you can do everything as normal even if you can't "see" them. When you try to save the DataFrame as csv file in the end you will see that all data were always there. The terminal output is just meant to give you a quick glance over the structure of your DataFrame, nothing more. As a side note, Pycharm is an IDE of your choice and has no relevance to your pandas question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas provides options for displaying DataFrame.

- `pd.options.display.width`
- `pd.options.display.max_columns`
- `pd.options.display.max_rows`

By default, pandas will display a truncated table if the DataFrame has more rows/columns than `max_rows`/`max_columns`.
You can adjust this if you want. Here's some sample code.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from random import random

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     f'c{col_no}': [random() for _ in range(100)] 
...     for col_no in range(15)
... })

>>> pd.options.display.max_columns, pd.options.display.max_rows
(0, 60)
>>> df
          c0        c1        c2  ...       c12       c13       c14
0   0.871826  0.415696  0.962756  ...  0.036385  0.405643  0.807471
1   0.531463  0.516149  0.811182  ...  0.588035  0.015000  0.447855
2   0.703785  0.793341  0.019570  ...  0.374489  0.057472  0.590761
3   0.762984  0.171603  0.127855  ...  0.357097  0.013220  0.132322
4   0.991035  0.113433  0.840822  ...  0.113895  0.707505  0.457993
..       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
95  0.438203  0.465847  0.287558  ...  0.236885  0.495121  0.115823
96  0.612054  0.709875  0.217789  ...  0.569730  0.779009  0.429083
97  0.396499  0.017465  0.075139  ...  0.032245  0.955732  0.708767
98  0.096672  0.227434  0.347087  ...  0.841708  0.031055  0.689640
99  0.123338  0.199680  0.284335  ...  0.328187  0.362656  0.379024

>>> pd.options.display.width = 200
>>> pd.options.display.max_columns = 15
>>> pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
>>> df
          c0        c1        c2        c3        c4        c5        c6        c7        c8        c9       c10       c11       c12       c13       c14
0   0.871826  0.415696  0.962756  0.337541  0.798125  0.641710  0.060606  0.268195  0.033646  0.713952  0.999305  0.266091  0.036385  0.405643  0.807471
1   0.531463  0.516149  0.811182  0.517024  0.907563  0.098621  0.486572  0.105661  0.233740  0.442899  0.882617  0.491250  0.588035  0.015000  0.447855
2   0.703785  0.793341  0.019570  0.656947  0.771691  0.163144  0.739283  0.775620  0.454568  0.739937  0.376440  0.783414  0.374489  0.057472  0.590761
3   0.762984  0.171603  0.127855  0.347233  0.681083  0.469366  0.074852  0.327360  0.583786  0.570660  0.918842  0.140252  0.357097  0.013220  0.132322
4   0.991035  0.113433  0.840822  0.198988  0.117649  0.148605  0.173794  0.126979  0.322275  0.766880  0.011601  0.918334  0.113895  0.707505  0.457993
5   0.027492  0.441665  0.015462  0.425986  0.876837  0.041831  0.385929  0.622585  0.893251  0.207410  0.126994  0.540103  0.132818  0.320651  0.135680
6   0.364498  0.777506  0.571290  0.463168  0.372986  0.727358  0.286281  0.060411  0.091997  0.599882  0.914836  0.713235  0.769993  0.912143  0.973625
7   0.021097  0.271388  0.903971  0.347351  0.255841  0.020190  0.307909  0.189683  0.635788  0.932846  0.740916  0.657532  0.347275  0.677888  0.027598
8   0.594859  0.905407  0.767936  0.929833  0.048191  0.084725  0.967413  0.183815  0.758094  0.686023  0.087515  0.512909  0.942502  0.858353  0.855532
9   0.899373  0.681138  0.546424  0.809373  0.174588  0.691135  0.755386  0.590502  0.161688  0.711284  0.918817  0.579863  0.599287  0.280585  0.691854
10  0.471923  0.523145  0.918165  0.406063  0.095486  0.972089  0.724117  0.231671  0.200418  0.733166  0.019452  0.128490  0.524909  0.895029  0.584772
... print all rows
```

Reference: [Options and settings - pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.describe_option.html#pandas.describe_option)

---

In PyCharm you can use [SciView](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-consoles.html#array) to explore DataFrame.

Click 'View as DataFrame' in 'Variables View' (right panel)
[image: PyCharm Python Console]

The DataFrame will opened in 'SciView' panel.
[image: PyCharm SciView]

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. Your suggested codes have certainly made me all the columns but all cramped up as no horizontal slider is available in PyCharm. Any idea how to get this horizontal slider in the pycharm run window so that all the columns can become visible without all going haywire.